# Sklearn neural network issue

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm doing some practice neural networks and am stuck on one issue. My network is not predicting the right result, even though it says the training score is 97%.

Here is my code:

```
# Import `datasets` from `sklearn`
from sklearn import datasets
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
# Import `train_test_split`
from sklearn.model_selection  import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier


# Load in the `digits` data
from sklearn.preprocessing import scale

iris = datasets.load_iris()

# split the data up - 3/4 for training, 1/4 for testing
data_train, data_test, name_train, name_test = train_test_split(iris.data, 
iris.target, test_size=0.25, random_state=0)

# Number of training features
# n_samples, n_features = data_train.shape

scaler = StandardScaler()
scaler.fit(data_train)
params_train_scaled = scaler.transform(data_train)
params_test_scaled = scaler.transform(data_test)

# 1 hidden layer, same size as the input layer
mlp = MLPClassifier(
    solver='lbfgs',
    hidden_layer_sizes=(iris.data.shape[1], ),
    random_state=0)
mlp.fit(params_train_scaled, name_train)

print(name_train)
print('Train score: %.3g' % mlp.score(params_train_scaled, name_train))
print('Test Score: %.3g' % mlp.score(params_test_scaled, name_test))
print

test_val = [[5.1, 3.5, 1.4, 0.2]]

print(mlp.predict(test_val))
```

My thought is it is how I scale the training and testing data, but I am not sure...

The output I am getting is:

> Train score: 1
>
> Test Score: 0.974

However, the predicted value should be 0, not 1.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you scale the training data, you should also scale the test data:

```
print(mlp.predict(scaler.transform(test_val)))
```